# Solution to generate MS Word document dynamically taking the contents from an HTML file

Tags: html, ms-word

Looking for a solution where I can generate a MS Word document dynamically with the machine readable data (HTML).

MS Word Template document + HTML file = Output Word document.

E.g.:
Content of Word document = I'm the < > document.

Content of HTML file     = `<td> example </td>`

Output Word document     = I'm the example document.

What could be the good methodology or tool to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open XML SDK using the "altChunk" method to "embed" the HTML file into the WordOpenXML Document "package" at the required "target" point. Word will convert and integrate the HTML into the document when it's opened in Word. See, for example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx

Comment: Seems to be a good solution, have to work on it though. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually pretty easy, once you get a feeling for it. Any other approach would involve automating the Word application interface and inserting the HTML from the Clipboard or from a file, so that Word uses its internal HTML converter. Or writing your own HTML converter.